# Difficulties printing the value I'm looking for, but solved using memcpy()--why?

Tags: c++, casting, memcpy

I need a fresh perspective on an attempt to print an 8 byte value. I am working on part of a program that talks to a sensor interface over TCP. What is tripping me up is interpretation of some values stored in memory from the sensor after a transfer is complete. Here is a small section of the code that is giving me problems:

```
void swapByteOrder(unsigned long long& ull) //converts big-endian to little-endian
{
    ull = (ull >> 56) |
        ((ull << 40) & 0x00FF000000000000) |
        ((ull << 24) & 0x0000FF0000000000) |
        ((ull << 8) & 0x000000FF00000000) |
        ((ull >> 8) & 0x00000000FF000000) |
        ((ull >> 24) & 0x0000000000FF0000) |
        ((ull >> 40) & 0x000000000000FF00) |
        (ull << 56);
}

struct sensor_fields {
    double packet_count;
    double timestamp;
    double car_x;
    double car_y;
    double car_z;
    double car_pd_x;
    double car_pd_y;
    double car_pd_z;
};

struct sensor_fields sensor_data;

void processSensor(struct sensor_fields* sensor_data, unsigned char data_packet[]) // function that bit shifts values from TCP packets and stores them into the appropriate sensor_data fields. Packets need to have byte order swapped first (done by the SwapByteOrder function, above)
{   
    unsigned long long raw_packet;

    raw_packet = unsigned long long((unsigned long long)(data_packet[15]) << 56 | 
    (unsigned long long)(data_packet[14]) << 48 | 
    (unsigned long long)(data_packet[13]) << 40 | 
    (unsigned long long)(data_packet[12]) << 32 | 
    (unsigned long long)(data_packet[11]) << 24 | 
    (unsigned long long)(data_packet[10]) << 16 | 
    (unsigned long long)(data_packet[9]) << 8 | 
    (unsigned long long)(data_packet[8]));

    swapByteOrder(raw_packet);
    memcpy(&sensor_data->timestamp, &raw_packet, sizeof(raw_packet));

    cout << "raw_packet is: " << (double)raw_packet << endl;       //This is NOT what I want, returns 4750079349732465269
    cout << "timestamp is: " << sensor_data->timestamp << endl;    //This is what I want, returns 3714057021.7766671
}
```

In the code above, raw_packet and sensor_data->timestamp are both 8 bytes, and each store the same values in memory. I will use this specific example: 0x75dab86700aceb41. I try printing this number directly using the (double) cast, and it does not return what I'm looking for. But after copying these 8 bytes using memcpy(), it does print what I want. Why is this?

I thought maybe there was an issue with signed/unsigned numbers, but I fail to see where this would be.

The reason why I care is that I'm getting the same incorrect value in another part of the program and would like to understand the difference in this case so I can correct the other.

Comment: The C-style cast, `(double)raw_packet` converts the *value* of `raw_packet` to it's nearest-representable `double` value. It doesn't do a bitwise copy.

Comment: You can use *horrible* tricks like `*(double*)(&raw_packet)` - but that's violating all sorts of aliasing rules and will ultimately lead you to premature senility.